# Look for a specific character in a sentence and print each word that has that charcter

Tags: c, string, pointers, character

I have to ask the user for a sentence and a character. I then have to find each word that has that character in that sentence and print those words. I cannot use strtok() Here is what I have so far. It is almost working but will not print the words properly. Could any one help? Sorry I am new to C..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char character;
char sentence[] = "this is my first sentence";
char *strPtr;
char word;

//printf("Enter a sentence\n");
//fgets(sentence, 500, stdin);

printf("Enter a character\n");
scanf("%c", &character);


printf("Words containing %c are: \n", character);

strPtr = sentence;

while(*strPtr != '\0')
{
    if (*strPtr == character)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strPtr);
    }
    strPtr++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to remember the index of the previous space character found, and wait until the next is found (or end of string), before extracting a word that contains the required character. Think what could happen if you choose the letter `e`. The word `sentence` must be printed only one.

Comment: Yes, use 2 pointers `sp` (start pointer) and `strPtr`. At the beginning and after each space set `sp` to the beginning of each word. When `strPtr` hits the next space set a `null-terminator` and print the word if it contains your character.

Comment: I have no idea how I would code that.... In the while loop I check when strPtr equals a space then I store the value of the beginning of that word as sp. And how do I print the word?

Comment: Note: the code cannot change the literal, because the literal will be in memory at a page marked as 'readonly'.  therefore I would incorporate the suggestion of two pointers, but output the word one character at a time until encountering a space.  The update both pointers to the next non-space character.  Do this all in a loop until a NUL char is encountered

Comment: @user3629249 not so: `sentence[]` is *initialised from* a literal. Had the declaration been `char *sentence = "this is my first sentence";` your comment would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char character;
    char sentence[] = "this is my first sentence";
    char word[sizeof sentence];
    char *strPtr, *wordPtr = word;
    int contain = 0;

    printf("Enter a character\n");
    scanf("%c", &character);

    printf("Words containing %c are: \n", character);

    for(strPtr = sentence; *strPtr != '\0'; strPtr++){
        if(isspace(*strPtr)){
            *wordPtr = '\0';
            if(contain)
                printf("%s\n", word);
            //reset
            contain = 0;
            wordPtr = word;
        } else {
            if(*strPtr == character)
                contain = 1;//find
            *wordPtr++ = *strPtr;
        }
    }
    *wordPtr = '\0';
    if(contain)
        printf("%s\n", word);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't print the last word. Needs to trigger on `'\0'` too.

Comment: I see, you check `contain` after loop in the demo.

Comment: I compiled and ran with `e`, no output. But you added more code to the demo linked.

Comment: I had been added before the  your comment. Edit link is not attached.;-)

Answer (score 0):

Or, without `ctype.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char character;
    char sentence[] = "this is my first sentence";
    char *strPtr = sentence;
    char *sp = sentence;

    //printf("Enter a sentence\n");
    //fgets(sentence, 500, stdin);

    printf ("\nCurrent string: %s\n\n", sentence);
    printf ("Enter a character: ");
    scanf ("%c", &character);

    printf ("\nWords containing %c are:\n\n", character);

    while (*strPtr) {                                   /* for each character   */
        if (*strPtr == character) {                     /* if match char        */
            while (*strPtr &&*strPtr != ' ') strPtr++;  /* find next space      */
            *strPtr = 0;                                /* null-terminate       */
            printf ("    %s\n", sp);                    /* print word           */
            *strPtr = ' ';                              /* replace w/original   */
            while (*strPtr && *strPtr == ' ') strPtr++; /* find next non-space  */
            sp = strPtr;                                /* set start pointer    */
        }
        else if (*strPtr == ' ')                        /* if no match & ' '    */
        {
            while (*strPtr && *strPtr == ' ') strPtr++; /* find next non-space  */
            if (*strPtr) sp = strPtr;                   /* set start pointer    */
        }
        else
            strPtr++;                                   /* advance pointer      */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/nostrtok

Current string: this is my first sentence

Enter a character: s

Words containing s are:

    this
    is
    first
    sentence

$ ./bin/nostrtok

Current string: this is my first sentence

Enter a character: e

Words containing e are:

    sentence

$ ./bin/nostrtok

Current string: this is my first sentence

Enter a character: x

Words containing x are:
```

Comment: cannot change a literal (as in replacing a char with NUL.)  suggest print one char at a time until next space or NUL.

Comment: It is not a **literal** it is a **character array**... A literal is `char *sentence = "this is my first sentence";`